# PostgreSQL NULL value cannot be found

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-null

select * from test;

[image]

select * from test where name not in ('amtf');

[image]

Why?

Comment: A comparison against NULL results in NULL, so `name not in ('amtf')` when `name` is `null` makes the condition `null` which then _behaves_ as false in the where clause (NOTE: That is not the same as being false).

Comment: The answer to [NOT IN in postgresql not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19517899/not-in-in-postgresql-not-working) explains it specifically for NOT IN.

Comment: Tks everyone!!!
select * from test where COALESCE(name,'') not in ('amtf');
OK

Comment: It is probably (slightly) quicker to do `select * from test where name not in('amtf') or name is null;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, the problem here is, that you're comparing against a `null` value, so it returns nothing, because it considers it as `false`, and I'll go even further that even if you say `where name <> 'admf'` it wont work, and even if you add more rows it will ignore the `null` row, and it's not just in PostgreSQL, it doesn't work in SQL-Server or MySQL either.

As you can see in these db<>fiddles [SQL-Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8061c14f3a6036632e1d126913bcc2c9), [MySQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8061c14f3a6036632e1d126913bcc2c9), and [PostgreSQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8061c14f3a6036632e1d126913bcc2c9).

And the reason why it doesn't work is, because you're saying `name` should not equal a specific value. First `name` needs to be a value it should not be equal to a value, but when `name` is `null` it doesn't have a value, and even more for a side note `null` itself is not equal `null`.

The way to solve it is to convert it to a empty string by using `COALESCE(name,'')` or in SQL-Server you can also use `isnull(name,'')`, and then compare it, or you can add `or name is null` which will return you all rows, including `null`, `where name <> 'some value'`.

Answer (score 1):

Well the condition is right and the response for that as soo .

```
select * from test where name not in ('amtf');
```

your query is saying : give me all the records that the name Column is not in ('amtf').

you have 2 column's on is amtf and the other is null.

amtf will no be brought because of the condition and the other column is null -> no name set